# Data not showing in datatable, Error: DataTables warning: table id=tableID - Ajax error

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm having a problem with my web app. When I run it I get Ajax error. I checked if it was a database problem , but app gets data successfully in getdata() method. The problem occurs somewhere in this script.

This is the definition of datatable:

```
<table id="tableID" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Party name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Start date and time</th>
            <th>Picture</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>
```

This is script that should fill datatable:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tableID').dataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/party/getdata",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "description", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "startDayTimeParty", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "image", "autoWidth": true }
                ]
            });
        });
```

And this is `getdata()` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getdata() {

    using (DBModels db = new DBModels()) {

        var partyList = db.party.OrderBy(a => a.name).ToList();
        return Json(new { data = partyList}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

party.cs class (database model class):

```
public partial class party
{
    public party()
    {
        this.clubID = 1;
    }

    public int partyID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime startDayTimeParty { get; set; }
    public int goingNumberGuests { get; set; }
    public int clubID { get; set; }
    public byte[] image { get; set; }

    public virtual club club { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please post the class `party` also or whatever class `db.party` is referring to. also post the view code where you're defining your table

Comment: Post is edited.

Comment: You can see DataTables manual to get the AJAX request summary: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7. Check returned JSON string if it satisfy DataTable requirements.

Comment: have you tried removing the byte[] column and see if the error still exists? guessing something with this column is breaking things.

Comment: I removed byte[] column, but the error is still there.